# How to trim leading spaces in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I have list of strings which all have leading whitespace
[image]

How do I remove it

Answer (score 0):

so I found a way to do this by using a sublime package [Trimmer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Trimmer)
[trimmer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFidI.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).